# Regex for identifying phone extensions in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking to identify extensions typed within a textarea in a form.
The extensions are 4 digits, but may be preceded in various ways.

- `x1234`
- `x.1234`
- `ext1234`
- `ext.1234`
- or just plain `1234`

I also do not want to match normal telephone numbers like `555-1212` and cause a false positive.

The regex I started using looks for 4 digits in a row,`/\d{4}/` however that matches 12345

I've attempted various other regex strings  and the closest I have come so far is:

`\b[a-zA-Z][^\-]?\D*\d{4}(?!\d)\b`

However, this does not match the criteria if the user only put 1234 into the textbox.  (Additionally, I feel my regex could be a bit more nightmare-ish than it needs to be and could be optimized with the proper know-hows.)

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test_text").keyup(function() {
    var str = $("#test_text").val();
    var search = str.match(/\b[a-zA-Z][^\-]?\D*\d{4}(?!\d)\b/);
    if (search != null) {
      $("#result").text("Success!");
    } else {
      $("#result").text("Failure. :(");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#test_text {
  width: 50%;
  resize: none;
}

#result {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Try the following:</p>
<ul>
  <li>8585 (Should be success) Wrong</li>
  <li>x8585 (Should be success) Correct</li>
  <li>It's Dave. 8585 (Should be success) Correct</li>
  <li>It's Dave. 85858 (Should be failure) Correct</li>
</ul>

<textarea id="test_text" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at the beginning of the final word with `\b`, alternate between `ext` and `x` and nothing, followed by optional `.`, followed by 4 digits and the end of the string:

```
(^| )(x|ext|)\.?\d{4}$
```

Also note that if you just want a boolean check to see if a regular expression matches a string, you can use `.test`, combined with the conditional (ternary) operator for more DRY code:

```js
$("#test_text").keyup(() => {
  var str = $("#test_text").val();
  $("#result").text(
    /(^| )(x|ext|)\.?\d{4}$/.test(str)
    ? "Success!"
    : "Failure"
  );
})
```

```css
#test_text {
  width: 50%;
  resize: none;
}

#result {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Try the following:</p>
<ul>
  <li>8585 (Should be success) Wrong</li>
  <li>x8585 (Should be success) Correct</li>
  <li>It's Dave. 8585 (Should be success) Correct</li>
  <li>It's Dave. 85858 (Should be failure) Correct</li>
</ul>

<textarea id="test_text" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I apologize if my other criteria may have been lost in my text above.  While this solution is correct on all other points - it still returns a false positive on normal phone numbers such as 555-1212.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that requirement. The tweak is simple - instead of a word boundary at the beginning, require a space, so that the `-` as in a phone number won't pass - see edit

Comment: This breaks should the user only enter a 4 digit extension in the form such as `1234`

Comment: Ok, so make the initial space optional

Comment: But now 555-1212 returns a successful match.  :)    I greatly appreciate your help.  I truly do.  I do not turn to posting to SO often, but I have been back and forth with this for hours.  ha!

Comment: Ok, then start with the beginning of the string *or* a space

Comment: This is it!  At long last - thank you very much for your solution as well as the added knowledge of a bit more regex.  :)